# How can I use M-x rgrep with the git grep command in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, grep, elisp

I want to be able to use the normal `M-x rgrep` workflow (entering a path, a pattern and displaying the linked results in a `*grep*` buffer) but using `git grep` instead of the normal `find` command:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -nH -e  {} +
```

I tried directly setting the `grep-find-command` variable:

```
(setq grep-find-command "git grep")
```

and using `grep-apply-setting`

```
(grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-command "git grep")
```

but neither seems to work. When I run `M-x rgrep` it just uses the same `find` command as before.

In fact, I'm pretty sure now that `rgrep` doesn't even use the `grep-find-command` variable, but I can't figure out where it's command *is* stored.

Answer (score 13):

What about `M-x vc-git-grep` (`C-x v f`).  Doesn't that do what you need?

It prompts you for:

- search pattern (default: token at point, or region)
- filename pattern (default: current file suffix)
- base search directory (default, current dir)

Works nicely for me.

Comment: Oh yeah, I actually didn't know about that command. For me, it also has the same problem with paging instead of returning the results directly. That could be fixed with the same advice.

Comment: And it is also not recursive with default `grep-files-aliases` patterns. Needed to add an advice for that.

Answer (score 12):

Turns out the relevant variable is actually `grep-find-template`. This takes a command with a few additional parameters:

- `<D>` for the base directory
- `<X>` for the find options to restrict directory list
- `<F>` for the find options to limit the files matched
- `<C>` for the place to put `-i` if the search is case-insensitive
- `<R>` for the regular expression to search for

The default template looks like this:

```
find . <X> -type f <F> -exec grep <C> -nH -e <R> {} +
```

To make the command work with `git grep`, I had to pass in a few options to make sure `git` doesn't use a pager and outputs things in the right format. I also ignored a few of the template options because `git grep` already restricts the files searched in a natural way. However, it probably makes sense to add them back in somehow.

My new value for `grep-find-template` is

```
git --no-pager grep --no-color --line-number <C> <R>
```

After some cursory testing, it seems to work.

Note that you should set this variable using `grep-apply-setting` rather than modifying it directly:

```
(grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-template "git --no-pager grep --no-color --line-number <C> <R>")
```

Since I don't use two of the inputs to `rgrep`, I wrote my own `git-grep` command which temporarily stashes the old `grep-find-template` and replaces it with mine. This feels a bit hacky, but also seems to work.

```
(defcustom git-grep-command "git --no-pager grep --no-color --line-number <C> <R>"
  "The command to run with M-x git-grep.")
(defun git-grep (regexp)
  "Search for the given regexp using `git grep' in the current directory."
  (interactive "sRegexp: ")
  (unless (boundp 'grep-find-template) (grep-compute-defaults))
  (let ((old-command grep-find-template))
    (grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-template git-grep-command)
    (rgrep regexp "*" "")
    (grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-template old-command)))
```

Answer (score 0):

With Emacs for Windows and Git Bash make sure PATH finds *git.exe* or `vc-git-grep` won't work:

```
  (let ((dir "C:/Program Files/Tools/Git/bin"))
    (setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ";" dir))
    (setq exec-path (append exec-path '(dir))))
```

`exec-path` is not enough... resaons are explained here: [Using git with emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930439/using-git-with-emacs)

Since `vc-git-grep` uses the directory of the buffer from which you run the function I also found a wrapper convenient:

```
(global-set-key [(control f8)]
            (lambda() (interactive)
              (with-current-buffer ROOT (call-interactively #'vc-git-grep))))
```

Here ROOT is a buffer (or function that evaluates a buffer) from whose directory the search begins.